# Remove CSS on il and ul inside a specific DIV

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like remove (add) some CSS class for each li and/or ul (the number of level is not fixed) inside a DIV `MyEntryPoint`.

Could you give me the selector to use ? I tried several solution

```
<div id="MyEntryPoint">
    <ul class="myMainItem open active">
        <li class="myItem">
            <ul>
                <li class="selected">Item1</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="myItem">Item2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="myMainItem">
        <li class="myItem">
            <ul>
                <li>Item3</li>
                <li>Item4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#MyEntryPoint').find('ul,li').removeClass...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a class to all li elements inside MyEntryPoint:

```
$('#MyEntryPoint li').addClass('classNameToAdd');
```

To remove a class of all li elements inside MyEntryPoint:

```
$('#MyEntryPoint li').removeClass('classNameToRemove');
```